# Add user inside a docker container to a goup on host system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to mount the docker socket as a volume into a Conatiner. The program runs as non-root user and hence is not part of the docker group and lacks the permissions for the docker socket.

I don't want to make the socket accessible to everybody nor do I want to run the program as root. Also I am using docker-compose and don't want to switch to plain docker.

So I somehow need to add the docker group to the non-root user but the at build time I can not get the id of the docker group. Creating a docker group is no help because the gid is incorrect(does not match).

At runtime in the container the program runs as non-root and therefore leaks permission to add itself to the docker group.

I read this https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#group_add which seems what I want but I can not find in in version 3 of the docker-compose specification.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4700 sounds like not possible since v3 which seems pretty sad

Comment: Compose file v3 is more oriented towards Swarm setups; there are several other options that aren't in v2.  It's reasonable to keep using `version: '2.4'` if you need options that aren't in the v3 format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have bumped into the same problem as Alex when I wanted to access to docker api from within a container running a django app.

"group_add" attribute, which was not available for a temporary period as shared by OP, helped me to overcome the issue without lifting tighter restrictions on docker.sock.

For a temporary period, I had to switch the perms from "srw-rw---T" (chmod 1660) TO "srw-rw-rwT" (chmod 1666) to be able to use docker APIClient from within container. (this is NOT a good practice... Don't do it on production)

After implementing the "group_add" attribute in docker-compose.yaml, I no longer need to do the risky perms easing.

First, I created the docker group in the container with the following statement in Dockerfile:

```
RUN groupadd -g 999 docker
```

(999 is the number of docker group in my machine. you can get it by "cat /etc/group")

Second, in docker-compose.yaml I added the following:

```
group_add:
  - docker
```

Hope this works out for anyone running into a similar problem.

(Note: I'm using rootless docker. Also, I'm running the container as a non-root user)